# Bypass open links js limitation

Tags: javascript, firefox

I pretty often need to open ~40-50 links from some page in tabs in firefox.

I'm curently writing user script for this, but have a problem. Firefox silently doesn't allow to open more than 20 tabs. Is there any way to bypass this limitation? It is for personal use, so I can change browser settings if it can help.

I have code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("article").length > 19)
    {
        alert($("article").length); 
        // show me 40, all elements have the same structure

        $("article").each(function() {
            $(this).find("a").each(function(){  
                window.open($(this).attr("href")); 
                // open only 20 tabs, no errors in console.                
            })
        });
    }                          
});
```

Comment: This seems like it would be a better fit on [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com) perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the number of allowed tabs in the `about:config` section.

- Open a new tab and type `about:config`.
- search for `pop`
- Find `dom.popup_maximum` in the list, double-click it, and edit your desired amount of tabs.